# Adding clickable 3DObject Rajawali Cardboard

Tags: android, android-studio, rajawali

I'm trying to add a simple Sphere Object to my VR app using Rajawali Libraries. My app should show a simple View ( with RajawaliCardboardRenderer, a sphere with the texture of an images ).
The question is : can I simply add a sphere or a 3DObject to that sphere which is gonna be clickable?

Here's my code :

```
    public class MyRenderer extends RajawaliCardboardRenderer {
    private Sphere sphere,sphere2;
    public MyRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initScene() {

        sphere = createPhotoSphereWithTexture(new Texture("photo", R.drawable.panorama));

        sphere2 = new Sphere(24,24,24);

        Material m = new Material();
        m.setColor(0);
        try {
            m.addTexture(new Texture("photo",R.drawable.zvirbloniu_parkas));
        } catch ( ATexture.TextureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sphere2.setMaterial(m);


        getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);
        getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere2);

        getCurrentCamera().setPosition(Vector3.ZERO);
        getCurrentCamera().setFieldOfView(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRender(long ellapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
        super.onRender(ellapsedRealtime, deltaTime);
        sphere2.rotate(Vector3.Axis.Y, 1.0);
    }

    private static Sphere createPhotoSphereWithTexture(ATexture texture) {

        Material material = new Material();
        material.setColor(0);

        try {
            material.addTexture(texture);
        } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 64, 32);
        sphere.setScaleX(-1);
        sphere.setMaterial(material);

        return sphere;
    }
}
```

Don't look at the form of the code, it is bad-written, it doesn't follow any pattern!

Comment: If there are also suggestions other than Rajawali libraries i will listen to them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the sphere2 as a child of the "scenario" sphere, in order to display it inside the scenario, something like this:

```
 sphere = createPhotoSphereWithTexture(new Texture("photo", .drawable.panorama));

 sphere2 = new Sphere(24,24,24);

 ...

 sphere.addChild(sphere2);
 getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);
```

Comment: I've already tried this solution, it doesn't work! 
Just for testing the solution in the onRendere() method, i've added the rotation to sphere2. I noticed that the entire view is rotating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you also need to set the position of the element in the scene, ex. sphere2.setPosition(20, 5, 10);, put it in the initScene method.

Comment: Right! Thank you! I have to learn a lot more about 3D. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The object picking mechanism of Rajawali will handle child objects. You could either add your new spheres directly to the scene, or to the photo sphere as children, whichever you prefer.

Comment: That's what I did : 
getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);
getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere2);

Comment: Then I am not clear on what you are asking. My interpretation of your question suggested you were asking if it could be done that way.